# Difficulty connecting by gmail with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm new to firebase. My google account can't connect to firebase. The problem comes from onActivityResult, my Toast returns me to "error".

I specify that i try on my device and i'm well connected to firebase because i find my activity on the analytic.

I have found my "default_web_client_id" here :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiTxB.png)

I ask the expert for help, where's my mistake?

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 999 ;
    GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    SignInButton signInButton;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_connexion);

        signInButton = findViewById(R.id.mygooglebutton);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        // Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signIn();
            }
        });
    }
        private void signIn() {
            Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
        }
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
            if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
                Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
                try {
                    // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                    GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                    firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
                } catch (ApiException e) {
                    // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                    // ...
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    }
    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Profile.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();

                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

Comment: When you are asking how to handle error you suppose to put error message in question body right? make e.getMessage()

Comment: The first Thing you should try is to debug this part of your program, read what apiexception you get and read what this api exception means. Did you provide a Fingerprint Sha certificate to authenticate your App?

Comment: Yes it's ok, i have add this more bottom.